# How to set React Native IS_TESTING environment variable for android?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

[here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3b6f6ca4d5fcee6f1bc6d6242e3e2ef136e4d546/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/systeminfo/AndroidInfoModule.java#L78-L80) react native uses the system property `IS_TESTING`.

But, in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging#warnings), it is not clear how to set this variable into the Android Environment.

It is mention that react native has the Environment Variable, but never tells how to set it.